# "session 'app' installation did not succeed. the application could not be installed. retry"

Tags: android-studio

Hoy me empezó a saltar un error al ejecutar un proyecto de Android Studio en mi dispositivo. Es un proyecto que ya ejecuté decenas de veces en este dispositivo pero cuando lo quise hacer hoy me dio el siguiente mensaje de error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Probé diversas maneras de solucionarlo buscando en internet. Ninguna me sirvió ya que no encontre este mensaje en específico. Lo que si me funcionó fue ejecutarla en otro dispositivo, es decir, que el problema se relaciona con el que uso habitualmente para probar los proyectos (Samsung J5 Prime). Entre las cosas que probé están:

-Clean y Rebuild project.

-Vi que en muchos problemas parecidos, para solucionarlo se dirigán a file > settings > build, execution, deployment > y desactivaban algo que decia "Instant Run", pero a mi no me aparece esa opción.

-Tambíen probé desinstalar y volver a instalar el IDE pero no cambió en absoluto.

Esto es lo que me sale en la pestaña Run:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desde ya, gracias!

Comment: Te sugiero liberes espacio o configura para que el .apk se instale en el almacenamiento externo, revisa mi respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema se describe aquì:

> ParcelableException: java.io.IOException: Requested internal only, but
> not enough space

Indica que tu dispositivo o emulador no cuenta con espacio suficiente para subir la aplicaciòn.

---

En algunos casos se define solo usar el almacenamiento interno para la aplicaciòn pero si no cuentas con espacio obtendràs el error, en este caso puedes optar por definir que la instalaciòn se realice externamente.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    ... >
```

Revisa:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location

Comment: Muchas gracias Jorge! hice las dos cosas que me recomendaste y de ambas maneras me funcionó. Saludos!

Comment: Si!! Era que no tenia espacio Samsung J5 Prime Muchas gracias por la informacion, Libere espacio y ! SOLUCIONADO